# How to Pass custom parameters to liferay's default render_portlet AJAX method

Tags: ajax, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to pass client's local time offset(from javascript) to server.
    http://localhost:8080/c/portal/render_portlet?p_l_id=10418&p_p_id=XXXcontacts_WAR_XXXcorebankingportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_t_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_pos=0&p_p_col_count=1&p_p_isolated=1&currentURL=%2Fweb%2Fxxxx

```
<render-weight>0</render-weight>
```

The portlet gets loaded by the liferay's built in Ajax method.

I need to intercept the Liferay's default render portlet ajax method.

Answer (score 1):

A renderURL has not a lot to do with Ajax - that's the realm of a resourceURL. You pass parameters just like to any other URL by adding them to the URL - in POST as well as in GET. You probably have constructed the above URL somehow, e.g. through `<portlet:renderURL />`, but you should use `<portlet:resourceURL />` instead. There's also a `Liferay` object available so that you can construct those URLs dynamically through Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am looking for something to do with the initial load of the portlet, with <render-weight>0</render-weight> Edited the initial Question.